# Visual Studio Installer - How to install C++ support on other drive, if possible

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I can't change the installation folder for these

Comment: I believe you have to install the entire IDE on the other drive not just 1 component in the setup.

Comment: Hi, May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this idea doesn't work, this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/change-installation-locations?view=vs-2022) states that you have to reinstall VS:

> You can select a different location only when you first install Visual
> Studio. If you've already installed it and want to change the
> location, you must uninstall Visual Studio and then reinstall it.

I also can't change the installation path on my computer.

[image]